# .net 3.5.1 - Issues reinstalling, repairing and everything else (I think)

Tags: windows-7, .net-framework

I did an emergency image of a corrupt HDD last week.

From what I can gather, .NET was on the corrupted part.

I have tried to reinstall but get the error of

```
You must use "Turn Windows features on or off in the control panel"
```

When I try and do the above, I get this error

```
An error has occured. Not all features were successfully changed
```

I have tried to run .NET repair tool and that doesn't help, just wants to send logs to Microsoft..

And finally, the last thin I have tried is the dotnetfx_cleanuptool which from I understand should remove it all so I can reinstall.

Any guidance on this?

Comment: What happen when you ran the tool to forcefully remove all versions of .NET from your computer?

Comment: Please run the Windows Explorer and copy the folder "C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\" to your document folder, also copy the file C":\Windows\Inf\setupapi.dev.log" , the "C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log" and the file "C:\Windows\winsxs\poqexec.log" to your document folder (otherwise you can't upload it), zip all files into 1 ZIP and upload the zip to your OneDrive/Dropbox and post a link here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Micrsoft Fix it tool to remove it first and then reinstall normally: http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall/